# Why does apt not display an error message even if flock is used?

Tags: apt, dpkg, synaptic, lock

Running script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
(
 flock 9 
  # ... commands executed under lock ...
 fuser -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock
 apt-get -f --assume-no install
) 9>/var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

as superuser does not display an error message. But if there is e.g. `synaptic` running,`apt-get` will display an error message:
"E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)".

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg` (and in turn apt) doesn't use `flock(2)` for locking. Checking the system calls, involved, it seems they use [`fcntl(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fcntl.2):

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=desc apt install foo |& grep -B2 F_SETLK
close(4)                                = 0
open("/var/lib/dpkg/lock", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW, 0640) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
close(4)                                = 0
```

And from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411531/2072269):

> In Linux, `lockf()` is just a wrapper around `fcntl()`, while `flock()`
>   locks are separate (and will only work on local filesystems, not on
>   e.g. NFS mounts). That is, one process can have an advisory exclusive
>   `flock()` lock on a file, while another process has an advisory
>   exclusive `fcntl()` lock on that same file. Both are advisory locks,
>   but they do not interact.

So `flock` isn't effective in locking it against other package management commands. (Thinking about it... if it were, then the subsequent `apt-get` would have failed anyway.)

---

The simplest way I can think of is to create an immutable `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file for the duration of the task.

```
touch /var/lib/dpkg/lock
chattr +i /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Or you can write a short C program (or any language that provides  an easy interface to `fcntl`) that uses `fcntl` to lock it the way dpkg does.

Comment: But there are no commands `fcntl` or `lockf` in terminal.

Comment: @jarno click on the fcntl link in the answer.

Comment: dpkg doesn't have to use commands to do locking. There are system calls for those. The flock command is merely a convenient wrapper around one of those system calls. There's no reason for all calls to have wrapper commands.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I want to lock dpkg database in a script so that user can choose interactively some packages, and thereafter do certain things with them by apt or dpkg without worrying that the packages have been changed e.g. by a background process in the mean time.

Comment: @jarno in that case, the simplest way I can think of is to create an immutable `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file for the duration of the task. Or you can write a short C program that uses `fcntl` to lock it the way dpkg does.

Comment: What do you mean by creating an immutable lock file?

Comment: @jarno `touch /var/lib/dpkg/lock; chattr +i /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: You can use a perl one-liner like `sudo perl -MFile::FcntlLock -e 'my $fs = new File::FcntlLock; $fs->l_type( F_WRLCK ); $fs->l_whence( SEEK_SET ); $fs->l_start( 0 ); $fs->l_len( 0 ); open my $fh, "+<", "/var/lib/dpkg/lock" or die $!; $fs->lock( $fh, F_SETLK ) or die $fs->error; warn "got lock\n"; system("run some commands")'` (requires package libfile-fcntllock-perl).

Comment: @muru would you create an answer? the chattr strategy is the most simple, correct solution (in my case, `chattr +i /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`)

Comment: @Marcus since this was already my answer :D I edited in the relevant comments instead.