# How does apt-get use /var/cache/apt/archives/lock?

Tags: apt, lock

I am curious of how `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock` used in `apt-get`.
 I found out that it is a regular file and I think it is used by calling `flock` on it every time `apt-get` needs to make some changes to `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/a/976982/158442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that `apt` is using [`fcntl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man2/fcntl.2.html) to control lock files.

---

Depend on what you are doing different locks will be created by `apt`, let's consider `sudo apt update` which [`apt-pkg/update.cc`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/e78844ba89fd15879333c1394fae9a65acebedc0/apt-pkg/update.cc#L30) is responsible of, and runs this condition before actually updating our sources lists:

```
if (Fetcher.GetLock(_config->FindDir("Dir::State::Lists")) == false)
```

Note that `_config->FindDir("Dir::State::Lists")` will return: `/lists`, you can find this out by running:

```
$ apt-config dump | grep lists
Dir::State::lists "lists/";
```

So `GetLock()` will creates a lock file in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, and if I run an other `sudo apt update` process I'll get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock ...
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

`GetLock()` itself lives here in [`apt-pkg/contrib/fileutl.cc`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/e78844ba89fd15879333c1394fae9a65acebedc0/apt-pkg/contrib/fileutl.cc#L215):

Let's have a look at its comment:

```c
// GetLock - Gets a lock file                       /*{{{*/
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
/* This will create an empty file of the given name and lock it. Once this
   is done all other calls to GetLock in any other process will fail with
   -1. The return result is the fd of the file, the call should call
   close at some time. */
```

So next time when I run `apt update` this function instead of creating the lock file will returns `-1` and our condition fails and we receive an error.

If we look into the codes of `GetLock`  we can see that it's using `fcntl` to provide its functionalities.

Basically `fileutl.cc` is a file utility containing two main function, which defines `GetLock` as "dpkg compatible lock file manipulation" method.

`fcntl` itself provides a bunch of system calls to manipulate file descriptors. One of the functionalities which is being provided by `fcntl` is "[POSIX record locks, also known as process-associated locks](https://gavv.github.io/blog/file-locks/#posix-record-locks-fcntl)":

```
man 2 fcntl
```

---

And I'm sure you already know the idea behind using lock files, but to make sure everyone who comes here knows about it:

[What is the purpose of lock file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530598/what-is-the-purpose-of-lock-file)

Comment: So ```/var/cache/apt/archives/lock``` are not used?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu Yes, it's being used... but `apt` does not uses `flock` to manage the lock process. it has it's own functions which are using `fcntl`.

Comment: @ Ravexina I see... And can you explain how it is being used?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu I think I already mentioned all necessary parts, you have to read the sources to find out what exactly happening here. What are you looking for? so we can help you exactly with that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that article.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu It's okay :) I'll try to update my answer to provide a little bit more information too.

Answer (score 1):

Apt and dpkg use lockfiles (in `/var/lib/`, not `/var/cache`) to ensure that package management actions and the package database are correctly in sync.

This means that if you install or remove the a package (like the `hello` package), the package database will be accurate, and your package manager will properly show the correct status of the package.

There are several possible solutions to ensure that package management actions and the package database are in sync. Lockfiles are the solution that the apt developers have chosen...mostly because it is a solution that is simple, easy to troubleshoot, and easy to understand.

Comment: He is asking how it's being done behind the scene I guess, he already should know the why...

Comment: So what does ```/var/cache/apt/archives/lock``` actually do?

Comment: @Ravexina seems a lot like an XY Problem question, so maybe knows the why...but maybe not.